# how to print only a specific data from the text extracted?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, split, text-extraction

I have already extracted text but i already need a section of the text.How do I only print the wanted section from the text while ignoring all the others?

BZN
 SEA
 AS
  LYS
 VIE
 OS

Section B Œ Code-share crossŒreferences

WITHIN:
 See Proviso of:
  1. 
FINLAND
 AY 
 2. 
INDIA
 9W 
 3. 
ITALY
 AZ
  4. 
JAPAN
 JL 
 5. 
MEXICO
 AM
  6.
 RUSSIA 
SU 
 7. 
UK
 BE 
 8. 
USA
 DL 
 9. 
VIETNAM
 VN

2 
AF  AIR FRANCE
 057

Section C Œ Proviso

1. WITHIN PTC2 
   I only want section B and not the other contents

import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('proviso1.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
for i in range(0,12):

```
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
print(pageObj.extractText())
```

pdfFileObj.close()

i have extracted using this

i only want to use section B

Comment: How about a regular expression selecting the substring from 'Section B' to 'Section C'?

Comment: im sorry but im very new to python. Can you tell e how will we identify the pattern in it?

Comment: I don't use python at all, I stumbled over your question due to the [tag:pdf] tag. But I'm positive Python does support regular expressions, so some python experts might step forward and give a hint here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Regular expression is the only way I can think of.

To understand how to write a regular expression as per requirement, please refer this -

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html